# Issue in uploading object to AWS S3 bucket using Java SDK in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

This is my code:

```
public class UploadObject {

    File samefile;
    String bucketName, bucketLocation, objectKey;

    public UploadObject(){
        System.out.println("Constructor of UploadObject...");
    }

    public void uploadObjectContent(File file) throws Exception{
        samefile = file;
        AWSCredentials credentials = FetchProperties.setCredentials();
        AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(FetchProperties.setCredentials());
        s3client.setEndpoint("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com");
        s3client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2));
        bucketName = "mybucket";
        objectKey = "myobject";
        try {
            if(!(s3client.doesBucketExist(bucketName)))
            {
                s3client.createBucket(new CreateBucketRequest(bucketName));
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Failure on creating bucket... " + e.getMessage().toString());
        }
        s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, objectKey, samefile).withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead));
    }
}
```

I am trying to upload object to my bucket but it shows me

> "Unable to calculate MD5 hash: file.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)".

I don't need to add MD5 hash on my code.

Comment: can you make sure file exists ? you dont need to have a new variable (samefile does not bring any value) so just pass file to the object request

Comment: I think the error is in the code calling the method, you are somehow passing a fielin the wrong position.

Comment: Thanks Henri. File is already exists in my system. I am trying to upload files to my S3 bucket. You are telling that no need to create an instance object for File class in above class right?

Comment: Thanks Guys. I solved the issue. Actual problem is on Chrome browser. I was trying in chrome browser it gets only file name so it shows me error  then I tried within eclipse it works. Now I can able to upload files into S3 bucket from eclipse IDE.